# Python pygame How to display 8 bit image

Tags: python, pygame, python-imaging-library

This is my code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pygame

i = ImageGrab.grab()
i = i.quantize(256)
xy = i.getbbox()
pd = pygame.display.set_mode((xy[2],xy[3]))
new_img = pygame.image.fromstring(i.tostring(),(xy[2],xy[3]),'P')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
    pd.blit(new_img,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

I am getting black screen,please help to resolve my issue.thanks Lot.

Comment: Could be a bug in pygame itself. Maybe report it that their issue tracker.

Comment: I not get any response from pygame Issue Tracker..

Answer (score 1):

The cause is the line `pygame.image.fromstring(..., 'P')` where the 'P' denotes an 8-bit encoding. The [pygame image fromstring documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.fromstring) states that "*the \"P\" format only creates an 8bit surface, but the colormap will be all black.*"

I got around this by manually copying the PIL image's colour palette across into the pygame surface. Code snippet follows:

```py
img = PIL.Image.open(...)  # read an 8-bit image
surface = pygame.image.fromstring(img.tobytes(), img.size, img.mode)  # img.mode is 'P'

new_palette = []
rgb_triplet = []
for rgb_value in img.getpalette():
    # this loop could be improved, but you get the idea
    rgb_triplet.append(rgb_value)

    if len(rgb_triplet) == 3:
        new_palette.append((rgb_triplet[0], rgb_triplet[1], rgb_triplet[2]))
        rgb_triplet = []

surface.set_palette(new_palette)
```

**Important:** in order to call `surface.set_palette` you must have first called `pygame.init()`, otherwise you'll get an exception.



**Another option:**

Another way I solved this was to write the image to disk, then load it straight into a pygame surface. This preserved the original colour palette. Note that this worked for me as the PIL image I was using wasn't originally read from disk at all, but created in memory by reading data from a URL (in this case a map tile from OpenStreetMap).

Code example follows:

```py
url = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{0}/{1}/{2}.png"  # serves up 8-bit PNGs
zoom = 10
tilex = 1
tiley = 1

tile_url = url.format(zoom, tilex, tiley)
imgstr = urllib2.urlopen(tile_url).read()
tile_img = PIL.Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imgstr))

temp_filename = "%s.%s.%s" % (zoom, tilex, tiley)
tile_img.save(temp_filename)

surface = pygame.image.load(temp_filename)
```

Obviously this isn't a high-performance solution due to the IO.